# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WSGIRequest' and 'str'

Tags: python, django

Stuck on this from last few days i want to join .NS string to the parameter passed by the index function and use that string to web.DataReader()

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    search = request.POST['search']
    graph_data(search)



def graph_data(request):
requestp = request
ex = '.NS'
st_name = requestp+ex
df = web.DataReader(st_name, data_source='yahoo', start='2019-01-01', end='2020-03-16')
```

Error:-

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WSGIRequest' and 'str'
```

Comment: I also remove +(operator) and use (,) but then it get converted into tuple...

Comment: requestp is not a string. You cannot concatenate a string to an object of type WSGIRequest. You need to pull the body out of the request and use that

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must convert `request` to string before using +

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.POST['search']
        graph_data(search)

def graph_data(request):
    requestp = request
    ex = '.NS'
    st_name = str(requestp) + ex
    df = web.DataReader(st_name, data_source='yahoo', start='2019-01-01',
                        end='2020-03-16')
```

Comment: please indent your answer correctly, even if the OP couldn't be bothered...